# Flash CS5 does not compile any timeline AS3 anymore

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

All the sudden Flash CS5 has stopped compiling any AS3. For example, if I create a new document and place these simple scripts on the timeline, the resulting SWF ignores the actions completely:

```
trace("HELLO"); // I get no "HELLO" in the output window

stop(); // on frame 2 I have a square, the SWF just loops endlessly between the two frames

alpha = .1; // the square is not fade as expected
```

In an AS2 document I get no trace() output, but actions DO work.

Does anyone have any ideas what's wrong? Any ideas how to fix this, other than a clean re-install?

Thanks.

Comment: Try running in debug mode (control-shift-enter).  I suspect that should fail as well saying something like "There is no code to debug".  If I'm right, I've seen this before (and there are solutions).

Comment: Either my initial tests (described above) had some other problem, or else actions have magically started working again after a restart. However trace() actions still don't work. And no, "omit trace actions" is not selected.

Comment: Also interesting: if I monitor the flashlog.txt file, I see the trace actions show up, but nothing shows up in the Output panel in Flash CS5. It seems it's just the Output panel is broken.

Comment: Mystery solved: the output panel "filter level" was set to None (I don't/remember how.)